# Saving only not empty data in apex

Tags: apex

my apex function looks the following:

```
 @AuraEnabled
    public static void UW_SavedData(Lead records){
        system.debug('test');
        system.debug(records);
        system.debug('test2');
        if(records != null){
            system.debug(records);
            string currentId = records.Id;
            Lead Prop = [SELECT Id, UW_occupency_rate__c, UW_otherRevenue__c, UW_roomCostOfSales__c, UW_OtherCostOfSales__c,
                                UW_OperatingCost__c, UW_LabourAndBenefitCost__c, UW_taxCost__c, UW_MaxRent__c
                                FROM Lead WHERE Id = :currentId];
            system.debug(Prop);
            Prop.UW_occupency_rate__c = records.UW_occupency_rate__c;
            Prop.UW_otherRevenue__c = records.UW_otherRevenue__c;
            Prop.UW_roomCostOfSales__c = records.UW_roomCostOfSales__c;
            Prop.UW_OtherCostOfSales__c = records.UW_OtherCostOfSales__c;
            Prop.UW_OperatingCost__c = records.UW_OperatingCost__c;
            Prop.UW_LabourAndBenefitCost__c = records.UW_LabourAndBenefitCost__c;
            Prop.UW_taxCost__c = records.UW_taxCost__c;
            Prop.UW_MaxRent__c = records.UW_MaxRent__c;
            update Prop;
            
            }     
        }
```

the goal of that function is to get data records... and then based on the ID find the relevant object and save the data.

However sometime my record object will not have all the parameters for example my record can look the following {'id':'12345', 'UW_occupency_rate__c":45}
however it will save UW_occupency_rate__c as 45 but all the other as empty

how can I save only the one that are not empty ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To update record all you need to have is the `id` of the record, you don't have to query for that record. So your code can be simplified to this.

```
 @AuraEnabled
    public static void UW_SavedData(Lead records){
        system.debug('test');
        system.debug(records);
        system.debug('test2');
        update records;  
    }
```

Few things happening here.

1. `update` will save record to database only if it is not null so you don't have to use the `if` condition.
2. if the record looks like your example `{'id':'12345', 'UW_occupency_rate__c":45}` the update statement will update the record in database where `id = 12345` and will update only the `UW_occupency_rate__c` field with the 45 value. The rest of the record will remain same.

Lastly, if the only thing you want to do in the method is to update some record, a better approach would be to use right component, for example [record-edit-form](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-edit-form/documentation), or [updateRecord](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_update_record) directly inside the js file.